# Dynamic Sitemap in Java EE app

Tags: sitemap

Is it possible to create a dynamic sitemap in a Java EE app? I'm using GWT and glassfish, but I doubt that matters.

The URLs I want to add are in this form: site.com/article/id/title-of-article

The best I think up with was to make a servlet and map it with *sitemap.xml, and have that create the XML for the sitemap.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done the same thing... exactly as you described.  The fact that it's Java EE is really beside the point. It's really the framework you're using (Spring MVC/Struts/custom) and how it maps views to URLs.  If it's REST style URLs as you stated, then it should be a pretty straight forward implementation generating XML from the servlet.  Be sure to use a streaming writer (StAX?) to keep your heap usage down.